# Calling a JavasScript function on a remote server from inside my JavaCode

Tags: java, javascript, httpurlconnection

There's a butt on a website that uses the `onClick` javascript function to run a JS function called `HiddenUsers.show()` or `HiddenUsers.hide()`

In my Java code, I've established an connection to this site using the `HttpURLConnection` class.  I'm able to post login credentials with a `BufferedOutputStream` and I can get responses with an `InputStream`.  But is it possible to send the command for that makes that button respond as clicked in turn triggering the JS function on the server side, or even better call the JS function itself from within my Java code?

Answer (score 0):

> is it possible to send the command for that makes that button respond as clicked in turn triggering the JS function on the server side

Perhaps I'm not fully following, but Javascript runs on the client (eg in the Browser), not on the server. So it doesn't make much sense to send javascript code to a webpage through HttpURLConnection. You can however, look through the webpage source and scripts and figure out what happens when the button is pressed and respond. For instance, if the button is a submit button you can use a HttpURLConnection to send get/post data from the form data associated with that button.

> or even better call the JS function itself from within my Java code

You can call javascript code through a javascript ScriptEngine contained with java, but javascript calls that change the DOM of a webpage would be out of context.

Comment: I did just that.  The code listener for the button in the source code triggers a javascript method called `HideUsers.hide()` or `HideUsers.show()` depending on the state of the button.  Based on what you said, how can I see what those JS functions are actually doing? Is there a way to view what they do since they aren't on my side.

Comment: You can see what those functions are doing by looking at the javascript code. This code is either in the page content you downloaded, or in linked javascript files which must be downloaded separately (all of which, from a Browser's prospective is 'on your side')

Answer (score 0):

There is a junvenile joke in your first sentence.

Outside of that, no, this isn't really possible.  I assume you're trying to automate gets and posts to another server from java.  It will receive the javascript, HTML etc... but it will not execute the javascript unless you go out of your way to get a javascript engine to execute it, and then what good will it do you to "show" something?

I'm assuming your angle is to acquire the users that are "hidden".  The users may already be in the HTML markup somewhere, in which case you'll just want to parse the HTML you get from your response and get them.  It is also possible that the ".show()" function gets the user list via an ajax call.  If that is the case your best bet will be to figure out what that ajax call is, and process it directly with another HttpURLConnection.